# Updating a row with null value and null writetime(value) in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

I have a record in cassandra table containing null value and want to update it to a new value

```
cqlsh:mydb> select * from mytable where id = 21;
 id      | value
---------+-------
 21      |  null

 cqlsh:mydb> select WRITETIME(value) AS timestamp_value from mytable where id = 21;

 timestamp_value
-----------------
            null
```

But `Insert` or `Update` statements have no effect.

```
UPDATE mytable USING TIMESTAMP 3392962145717000  SET value = "new value" WHERE id=21;
INSERT INTO mytable (id,value) VALUES (21,"new value") USING TIMESTAMP 3392962145717000;
```

After executing the timestamp and value remain unchanged and no error is reported.
Is there a way to update the row with a new value?

Comment: P.S It looks like `WRITETIME(value)` wrongly reports `null` because an UPDATE with very high `TIMESTAMP` (9992962145717000) did actually work and the value and timestamp were updated. what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

What Cassandra version are you using?

I did the test in Astra and it works

```
token@cqlsh:catalog>  CREATE TABLE catalog.mytable (
           ...  id int,
           ...  value text,
           ...   PRIMARY KEY (id)
           ...  );
token@cqlsh:catalog> INSERT INTO catalog.mytable (id) VALUES (21);
token@cqlsh:catalog> select WRITETIME(value) AS timestamp_value from catalog.mytable where id = 21;

 timestamp_value
-----------------
            null

(1 rows)

token@cqlsh:catalog> UPDATE mytable USING TIMESTAMP 3392962145717000  SET value = 'new value' WHERE id=21;

token@cqlsh:catalog> select * from mytable where id=21;

 id | value
----+-----------
 21 | new value
```

Comment: cqlsh 6.1.0 | Cassandra 4.1.3 | CQL spec 3.4.6 | Native protocol v5

Comment: after you inserted a value then delete it USING TIMESTAMP x, WRITETIME(value) will return null, then you basically don't know what timestamp was used and can only update the row if you find a higher one then x used in delete statement